# Pip fails to install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow, on an offline computer with Windows 7. I have previously done this using pip on the whl file and it worked, but now that I'm trying to do the same with tensorflow-gpu, I get an unexpected error:

```
> pip install -v tensorflow_gpu-1.2.0-cp36-CP36m-win-amd64.whl
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0 from file:///C:/Users/T0024528/Documents/installers/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown==2.2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib==0.9999999 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach==1.5.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.weakref==1.0rc1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg (from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.2.0)
Cleaning up...
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
(self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 75, in create_connection
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 151, in _new_conn
self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048262B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
timeout=timeout
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 640, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 287, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048262B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\outdated.py", line 126, in pip_version_check
headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 487, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048262B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

it seems that pip tries to download https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json, which it was not trying to do before. How can I solve this?

Comment: Seems like you have a networking problem before anything else. You should verify you have connectivity to the urls in question.

Comment: Can you visit `https://pypi.python.org/` in your browser? If not, then it's an issue with your local network as @pvg has stated.

Comment: I don't have access to the internet from my computer, yet the cpu version of tensorflow that I downloaded on another computer worked perfectly, but for some reason the GPU version raises this error

Comment: `pip` trying to get https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json seems like a purely pip related behavior. I am not aware of any differences in Tensorflow CPU vs GPU pip installers that would trigger this. It might have been that the file was already "in the cache" on your other machine. If you can't connect your machine to internet, maybe you can use http://doc.devpi.net/1.2.1/quickstart-pypimirror.html

Answer (score 0):

For similar problems this helped me:

1. Set `https_proxy` env. variable to your HTTPS proxy:

   ```
   > set https_proxy=myproxy.org:port
   > pip install ...
   ```

I suggest to set `https_proxy` as system or user-level env. variable for the future...

2. Or provide the proxy as a parameter to `pip`:

   ```
   > pip --proxy=myproxy.org:port ...
   ```

AFAIK, on Windows 7, you can display your proxy settings by:

```
> netsh winhttp show proxy
```

(hopefully including httpS proxy, too...)